# Burning a Windows iso that is too big

Tags: dual-boot, windows, iso, burning

I'm trying to install Windows as a dual-boot. The iso file is the last Windows release: Windows_10_Oct_It and I've tryed so many softwares but everyone says: There's a file too big to burn into a usb. The file is install.wim, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the large Windows file and still boot from it. Check out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/split-a-windows-image--wim--file-to-span-across-multiple-dvds